# Generic name for Production and Staging

Tags: single-word-requests, software

In computer science, the environment in which software runs is called "development", "staging", and "production".

I am faced with a piece of software that can only exist in one environment. It goes out and retrieves data, but only one version of it can exist in the company. This is to prevent us from being double-billed.

I was thinking of calling the new environment "singleton" to describe to people that only one instance of it should exist.

Is there a better word to describe the environment?

Comment: Sounds spooky. Ask Mr. Snowden.

Comment: Singleton seems likely to confuse people, any reason you can't just call it "production", or "name-of-product"?

Comment: How do you test it?

Comment: @Jim The environment has the tests for it. The most important thing is that not more than one environments run/test it.

Comment: @barbecue the reason I don't want to call it "production" is because the mindset. When people see something running on "production", it is assumed there's an equivalent in "staging", "dev", "qa". However, if the environment name is "only-one-instance" (or something like "singleton"), then it is assumed that "there can be only one".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are addressing software engineers, 'singleton' works well, since that's the term for

> [a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single" instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

In other contexts, it can mean an only child or an unmarried person, but since you are talking to IT people, I think you found the best possible term.